# Get numbers or numbers directly next to letters from a string

Tags: python

I have a list of strings in python:

```
s = ['64b DRIVE RD', 'DRIVE RD 64', 'Unit 1 Drive RD 64b', '484 South Drive 84b WA', '64Drive']
```

What I want to do is remove any word that is composed solely of letters. So in the above list, I want my output to be:

`['64b', '64', '1 64b', 484 84b, '64Drive']`

I able able to get the list with only numbers through the following:

`[" ".join(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', i)) for i in s]`

output:

```
['64', '64', '1 64', '484 84', '64']
```

But am unsure how to keep the letter attached to any number.

Comment: `r'[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*'`?

Comment: I would approach it differently. For each word, check if there is any number. If yes, keep that word. Move on to the next word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) a few times with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). From right to left, remove all words consisting of letters only, then compress more than one whitespace into a single blank, then remove leading and trailing whitespace.

```
import re
s = ['64b DRIVE RD', 'DRIVE RD 64', 'Unit 1 Drive RD 64b', '484 South Drive 84b WA', '64Drive']

s = [re.sub(r'(^\s+|\s+$)', '', re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'\b[A-Za-z]+\b', '', x))) for x in s]
print(s)
# ['64b', '64', '1 64b', '484 84b', '64Drive']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good only regex is not very precise.
use this regex. `r'[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*'`

```
import re
s = ['64b DRIVE RD', 'DRIVE RD 64', 'Unit 1 Drive RD 64b', '484 South Drive 84b WA', '64Drive']
res  = [" ".join(re.findall(r'[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*', i)) for i in s]
print("res: ",res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without importing re, too:

```py
s = ['64b DRIVE RD', 'DRIVE RD 64', 'Unit 1 Drive RD 64b', '484 South Drive 84b WA', '64Drive']

[' '.join(word for word in string.split() if not word.isalpha()) for string in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```python
def remove_letters_only(words):
    return (' ').join([word for word in words.split(' ') if not word.isalpha() ])


s = ['64b DRIVE RD', 'DRIVE RD 64', 'Unit 1 Drive RD 64b', '484 South Drive 84b WA', '64Drive']

new_s = list(map(remove_letters_only, s))

print(new_s)
```

**Output:**

```
['64b', '64', '1 64b', '484 84b', '64Drive']
```